# Sum of Count throw an exception, but SelectMany().Count() not throw

Tags: c#, linq

```
db.Projects.Select(x => new Statistic {
                          Posts = x.Members.Sum(m => m.Posts.Count())
                        })
```

Why this code throw an exception:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

And this code works fine

```
db.Projects.Select(x => new Statistic {
                           Posts = x.Members.SelectMany(m => m.Posts).Count()
                        })
```

?

The structure is intuitive:

Project has many Members.
Member has many Posts.

```
public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

**EDIT: Final working code**

```
db.Projects.Select(x => new Statistic {
                          Posts = (int?)x.Members.Sum(m => m.Posts.Count()) ?? 0
                        })
```

Comment: `Posts` is null.  Trying to convert `null` to `int` for `Sum()` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your `Sum` or `Count()` is throwing a null.

Allow `Posts` within your `Statistic` class to be nullable and cast values to nullable ints.

```
db.Projects
    .Select(x => new Statistic
    {
        Posts = (int?)x.Members.Sum(m => (int?)m.Posts.Count())
    })
```

Or get the value with `.Value`. The `.Value` approach will still throw an exception if the sum of counts still results in a null value.

```
db.Projects
    .Select(x => new Statistic
    {
        Posts = x.Members.Sum(m => (int?)m.Posts.Count()).Value
    })
```

Comment: Yea, thx a lot! This variant is works `Posts = (int?)x.Members.Sum(m => (int?)m.Posts.Count() ?? 0) ?? 0`

Comment: If u can pls explain why its happens?

Comment: Why does this fix the problem? Without knowing the exact structure or contents of your data, it is hard to say for sure but either your `Count()` or your `Sum()` is returning a `null`. Casting these to nullable ints `int?` allows for the `Sum()` in the case that `Count()` is null to handle said null.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Members` property can be null. You should add a check if it's null and then your first approach would work fine.

For example:

```
db.Projects.Select(x => new Statistic {
    Posts = x.Members==null? 0 :  x.Members.Sum(m => m.Posts.Count())
})
```

Comment: i think Members cannot be null, it should be an empty Collection